# Letter Class | How to Adjust Default Spacing

Tags: document-classes

Is seems in the letter class by default, there is a huge space/gap in between the title and the body of the letter.  How would I decrease this space between the two?  Please see image in link below along with the code.

[image]

```
% Cover letter using letter.sty
\documentclass[letterbox, 10pt]{letter} % Uses 10pt
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}

%Use \documentstyle[newcent]{letter} for New Century Schoolbook postscript font
% the following commands control the margins:
\topmargin=-1in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight=8in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin=0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\textwidth=6.5in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin

% Color definitions
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666}  %666666
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} %2b2b2b , changes color of section name, and everything under it
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A} %6A6A6A, changes color of phone and address
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333} %333333

% Set main fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Bol,ItalicFont=Lato-RegIta]{Lato-Reg}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway    /]{Raleway-ExtraLight}

% Name command, for customizing name at top
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
    \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}
    \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\selectfont #1 %Try Lato-Hai for lighter contrast, First Name
    \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 %Last name
 } \\[5pt]
 \centering{
    \color{headings}
    \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}    \selectfont #3}
\vspace{-5pt} %Distance between Name heading and education. This font is just for email, phone, address in title
}



\begin{document}

\signature{Susan R. Bumpershoot}           % name for signature 
\longindentation=0pt                       % needed to get closing flush left

\let\raggedleft\raggedright                % needed to get date flush left


\begin{letter}{Ms. Terri Roberts \\

        Senior Staff Recruiter \\
        XYZ Corporation \\
        Rt. 56 \\
        Anytown, New Jersey 05867}


    \begin{center}
      \namesection{xxxx}{x. xxxxx}{\href{mailto:xxxxx}{\color{blue}    \underline{xxxx@gmail.com}} | xxx-xxx-xxxx | Chicago, IL xxxxx}

    \end{center}
    \vfill % forces letterhead to top of page


    \opening{Dear Ms. Roberts:} 

    \noindent PARAGRAPH ONE: State reason for letter, name the position or type 
    of work you are applying for and identify source from  which  you 
    learned   of   the  opening.  (i.e.  Career  Development  Center, 
    newspaper, employment service, personal contact). 

    \noindent PARAGRAPH  TWO:  Indicate why you are interested in the position, 
    the company, its products, services - above all, stress what  you 
    can  do  for  the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain 
    how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate  for 
    the  position.  If  you have practical work experience, point out 
    specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat 
    the  same  information  the reader will find in the resume. Refer 
    the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes 
    your  qualifications,  training,  and experiences. The purpose of 
    this section is to strengthen your resume  by  providing  details 
    which bring your experiences to life. 

    \noindent PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and  indicate  your 
    flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in 
    the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For 
    example,  state that you will be in the city where the company is 
    located on a certain date and would like to set up an  interview. 
    Or,  state  that  you  will  call  on a certain date to set up an 
    interview. End the letter by thanking  the  employer  for  taking 
    time to consider your credentials. 

    \closing{Sincerely yours,} 



    \encl{}                 % Enclosures

\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` does not take an argument

Comment: You have `\vfill`  spacing there which is forcing this space to be as large as possible. the comment `% forces letterhead to top of page` is just wrong, it is forcing the body of the letter down.

Comment: you must be using luatex or xetex but have specified pdftex to hyperref `! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `pdftex',
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The space was being forced by the `\vfill` added at that point which forces the letter body to the bottom of the page, I also added some other comments inline.

```
\documentclass[letterbox, 10pt]{letter} % Uses 10pt
\usepackage[
% no pdftex
, hidelinks]{hyperref}

%Use \documentstyle[newcent]{letter} for New Century Schoolbook postscript font
% the following commands control the margins:
\topmargin=-1in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight=8in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin=0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\textwidth=6.5in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin

% Color definitions
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666}  %666666
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} %2b2b2b , changes color of section name, and everything under it
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A} %6A6A6A, changes color of phone and address
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333} %333333

% Set main fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}

% I don't have this font
%\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Bol,ItalicFont=Lato-RegIta]{Lato-Reg}
%\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = fonts/raleway    /]{Raleway-ExtraLight}

% Name command, for customizing name at top
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
% no \centering{
    \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}
% I don't have this    \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}
\selectfont
 #1 %Try Lato-Hai for lighter contrast, First Name
% I don't have this     \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
\selectfont
 #2 %Last name
%no }
% no line to end \\[5pt]
%no \centering{
    \color{headings}
% I don't have this font    \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}
\selectfont #3
%}
% leave blank line before vspace

\vspace{-5pt} %Distance between Name heading and education. This font is just for email, phone, address in title
}



\begin{document}

\signature{Susan R. Bumpershoot}           % name for signature 
\longindentation=0pt                       % needed to get closing flush left

\let\raggedleft\raggedright                % needed to get date flush left


\begin{letter}{Ms. Terri Roberts \\

        Senior Staff Recruiter \\
        XYZ Corporation \\
        Rt. 56 \\
        Anytown, New Jersey 05867}


    \begin{center}
      \namesection{xxxx}{x. xxxxx}{\href{mailto:xxxxx}{\color{blue}    \underline{xxxx@gmail.com}} | xxx-xxx-xxxx | Chicago, IL xxxxx}

    \end{center}
% no!!!    \vfill % forces letterhead to top of page


    \opening{Dear Ms. Roberts:} 

    \noindent PARAGRAPH ONE: State reason for letter, name the position or type 
    of work you are applying for and identify source from  which  you 
    learned   of   the  opening.  (i.e.  Career  Development  Center, 
    newspaper, employment service, personal contact). 

    \noindent PARAGRAPH  TWO:  Indicate why you are interested in the position, 
    the company, its products, services - above all, stress what  you 
    can  do  for  the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain 
    how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate  for 
    the  position.  If  you have practical work experience, point out 
    specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat 
    the  same  information  the reader will find in the resume. Refer 
    the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes 
    your  qualifications,  training,  and experiences. The purpose of 
    this section is to strengthen your resume  by  providing  details 
    which bring your experiences to life. 

    \noindent PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and  indicate  your 
    flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in 
    the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For 
    example,  state that you will be in the city where the company is 
    located on a certain date and would like to set up an  interview. 
    Or,  state  that  you  will  call  on a certain date to set up an 
    interview. End the letter by thanking  the  employer  for  taking 
    time to consider your credentials. 

    \closing{Sincerely yours,} 



    \encl{}                 % Enclosures

\end{letter}


\end{document}
```